# Cannot run steam on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, games, steam

So my problem is that when I restart my computer, steam firstly can be runned. But after some time(about 1 minute or so) it lags and just doesn't do anything at all. Shutting down doesn't help due to steam working still in the background. After I shut it down, and exit steam, it never runs again if I don't restart the computer.
I tried using 'sudo steam' command and it shows the following :

Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice...
...and PulseAudio has been explicitly chosen, so using it.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/run/user/0/snap.steam/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
xterm: error while loading shared libraries: libXft.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried using just 'steam' and it just tries to run steam but maybe encounteres some troubles becouse it just shw me never-ending lines that I wouldn't be able to put here.
I have also installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my HDD, there steam works perfectly fine. But I want to use Ubuntu on my nvme m.2 ssd, and here there are several problems, not only with steam. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but it didn't help.

I really hope someone can help me, as I already looked up on a lot of cites and never found something similar to my problem.
Thank you
p.s. I am also a very begginer...

Comment: It might be some damaged files. Have you already tried reinstalling Steam?
Otherwise if it’s about Ubuntu in general it could be an hardware problem.

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing it? I had a similar problem and as the others have suggested, I did a complete erase and reinstall with Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: Yes, I have tried reinstalling it several times. In fact, I even reinstalled the whole OS but the problem wasn't solved, sadly. I tried the suggestion to erase steam and reinstall from an official site, and at first it seemed like all was solved : games were being installed and everything was fine. But then the app crashed. After that I was able to run it, but the games downloading was endless. There was no indicator about the status of download and nothing was happening. I tried closing steam, it closed, but I couldn't end its background activity, so I deleted it once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using synaptic package manager (apt) or software center(snap) to fully remove your existing steam installation then get a fresh .deb package from the official steam website and try reinstalling. Or you can try an alternate install method like flatpak.